# Resque job returning with error: "No such file or directory - getcwd"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I have a really simple job:

```
class MyJob
  @queue = :high

  def self.perform(user_id)
    user = User.find(user_id)
    MyMailer.send_email(user).deliver
  end

end
```

If I run it manually `MyJob.perform(some_id)`it works perfect. However, when Rescue is executing it, it returns this error:

```
Exception
    Errno::ENOENT Error
    No such file or directory - getcwd

 shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_view/template/resolver.rb:221:in `expand_path'  shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_view/template/resolver.rb:221:in `initialize'  shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_view/template/resolver.rb:251:in `new'  shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_view/template/resolver.rb:251:in `instances'  shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:16:in `<class:LookupContext>'  shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:12:in `<module:ActionView>'  shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'  shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/abstract_controller/view_paths.rb:45:in `lookup_context'  shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionmailer-3.2.12/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:456:in `process'  shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionmailer-3.2.12/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:452:in `initialize'  shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionmailer-3.2.12/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:439:in `new'  shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionmailer-3.2.12/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:439:in `method_missing'  releases/1111111111111/app/jobs/my_job.rb:6:in `perform'
```

Have any ideas why might be happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes Sky.  You are right about it needing to be restarted.

Some people received this error after trying to run from an already deleted directory.

I received this error after switching databases and leaving the server running. The old server info was still showing up but I was getting this error. Restarted my rails server and everything works fine with the new db.

Basically it means that there is a significant state change on the server, and your environment needs to be reset/restarted.

Answer (score 1):

I started having this same issue on my production environment. After some investigation I found that this was caused by my resque workers failing to be properly restarted on each capistrano deployment.

Comment: How do you manually restart them? rake resque:scheduler RAILS_ENV=production
????

Comment: Sky mayhew how did you fix this?